# Android AES Encryption from C# to Java

Tags: java, c#, android, encryption, aes

I am converting my C# encryption code to Android.

I am facing issue like I am not able to encrypt the text as same as C#.
Below I copy paste both code.

Both are working code regarding using it you can use any password & any plain text .You will find both have different output.

**C# CODE**

```
System.security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged AES = new System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged();
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider Hash_AES = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

final MessageDigest Hash_AES = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

        String encrypted = "";
        try {
            byte[] hash = new byte[32];
            byte[] temp = Hash_AES.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass));
            final byte[] temp = Hash_AES.digest(pass.getBytes("US-ASCII"));

            Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16);
            Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16);
            AES.Key = hash;
            AES.Mode = System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB;
            System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform DESEncrypter = AES.CreateEncryptor();
            byte[] Buffer = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
            encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(DESEncrypter.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length));
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
        return encrypted;
```

Here is my Android java code.

**ANDROID JAVA CODE**

```
private static String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/ECB/NoPadding";
private static String ALGORITHM = "AES";
private static String DIGEST = "MD5";
byte[] encryptedData;

public RijndaelCrypt(String password,String plainText) {

    try {

        //Encode digest
        MessageDigest digest;           
        digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(DIGEST);            
        _password = new SecretKeySpec(digest.digest(password.getBytes()), ALGORITHM);

        //Initialize objects
        _cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);

       _cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, _password);
        encryptedData = _cipher.doFinal(text);

    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Invalid key  (invalid encoding, wrong length, uninitialized, etc).", e);
        return null;
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Invalid or inappropriate algorithm parameters for " + ALGORITHM, e);
        return null;
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "The length of data provided to a block cipher is incorrect", e);
        return null;
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "The input data but the data is not padded properly.", e);
        return null;
    }               

    return Base64.encodeToString(encryptedData,Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Should I need to use "US-ASCII" in pass or does it take it?

Comment: I think you need to pass "US-ASCII" encoding scheme in getBytes() method of Java code. Its always a good practice to pass a Charset scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use the same mode of operation: either ECB or CBC
- Use the same character set: it's best to stick to "UTF-8"
- Use the same key: in the C# code you're doubling the 128-bit key to 256 bits

When using CBC with a random IV, it is expected that the ciphertext differs for the same plaintext. The decryption is the operation that determines whether you succeeded.

Note that ECB is not semantically secure. Use CBC with a random IV. The IV doesn't have to be secret, so you can just prepend it to the ciphertext and slice it off before decryption.

It's better to use an authenticated mode like GCM or EAX or if it's not provided an encrypt-then-MAC scheme. It's hard to implement it correctly yourself so stick to some library that does this for you like RNCryptor.

Comment: @Artojom Thank you for suggestion .on I removed the random IV .still I found cipher give me wrong value.
Any idea where  what was wrong it code.?

Comment: You should use the same key. I extended my answer.